# Ошибка composer расширение intl php mac OS

Tags: php, composer

хочу развернуть админку yii2 kit start пишу команду `composer.phar install` и выходит ошибка

> The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.

Все перевел, знаю что не хватает расширения, не пойму как установить, где только не искал. 
OS MAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. установите composer глобально (лишним не будет): https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally
2. стяните с packagist себе starter-kit

*composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev trntv/yii2-starter-kit*